# Forcing Proportion Lock on Layout Element

Tags: unity

I'm trying to develop a Card-Game in Unity3D using 2D mode.

Every **Card GameObject** on my Scene contains a `Layout Element` Component with following parameters:

[image: LayoutElement]

The parent container, a `Panel` has a `Horizontal Layout Group` Component with this settings:

[image: Horizontal Layout Group]

Now i have this parent control multiply times on my Scene with different sizes. But now its destroys the proportions of my Card, as you can see below on the screenshot.

[image: Current Scene]

So is there a way to ensure the proportions of my Card when scaling or shrinking the parent Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an [AspectRatioFitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html) component, maybe on the parent panel and maybe on the cards themselves.